# Update works for main object but not updating children

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 3 objects'

- `formBuilderDto`
- `FormBuilderElements`
- `FormBuilderSelectOptions`

Here is a better view of what they look like.

```
public class formBuilderDto : Entity
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FormBuilderElements> elements { get; set; }

    public formBuilderDto() {
        elements = new List<FormBuilderElements>();
        name = "";
        active = true;
    }
}

public class FormBuilderElements : Entity
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string placeholder { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FormBuilderSelectOptions> selectOption { get; set; }
    public ElementType type { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public bool resizeable { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public FormBuilderElements()
    {
        selectOption = new List<FormBuilderSelectOptions>();
        label = "";
        placeholder = "";
        required = false;
        type = ElementType.TextBox;
        height = 0;
        resizeable = false;
        order = 0;
    }
}

public class FormBuilderSelectOptions : Entity
{
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public FormBuilderSelectOptions() {
        order = 0;
        label = "";
        value = "";
    }
}
```

When I try to run the update code below, it updates `formBuilderDto` correct but the children's are not updated at all. If I run the debugger and look into the object `n` just before `UpdateAsync(n)` then I can see n is updated with the new values.

The code returns no error and in my api I receive the "updated" element, but the db has not been updated and if I reload the element on the page it's not updated.

**UpdateAsync**

```
public async Task<formBuilderDto> UpdateAsync(formBuilderDto input)
{
    if (input.Id > 0)
    {
        var n = await _repository.GetAll()
            .Include(i => i.elements)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.selectOption)
            .Where(i => i.Id == input.Id)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        n = ObjectMapper.Map<formBuilderDto>(input);
        await _repository.UpdateAsync(n);
        return n;
    }
    return input;
}
```

I've also tried `ObjectMapper.Map(input,n);` but that didn't change anything. Do anyone know what I done wrong.

Comment: About the "ObjectMapper.Map", I assume you are using AutoMapper, right? How do you check the data in the database? I suggest you could try to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) recheck it again. If the data still doesn't change, as you said, the object n is updated with the new values before UpdateAsync(n), I think perhaps the issue is related to the `_repository.UpdateAsync()` method, check the related code and make sure it save changes to the database.

Comment: @ZhiLv I'm using ssms to check, I've also check with the database tool provided for Visiual Studio. As i said in the description, i've debugged n and seen that the data changes before our updateAsync.

Comment: Based on your code, I also created a sample using the following code (use automapper): `var n = _context.FormBuilderDtos.Include(c => c.elements).ThenInclude(c => c.selectOption) .Where(c => c.ID == formBuilderDto.ID).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(); n = _mapper.Map<FormBuilderDto>(formBuilderDto); _context.SaveChanges();`, if the n object contains the updated value, after calling the Dbcontext SaveChanges() method, it will update the data to database, it works well on my side, you can try to use it. Or try to use `_context.Update(n);_context.SaveChanges();` to save the changes.